# Assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded - but all my projects target .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to fix an intermittent exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException saying "Could not load file or assembly
>   'dbpProject' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a
>   runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Apparently `dbpProject` refers to my database project.

Thinking that maybe one of the projects in my solution was to blame, I went and changed them all to target `.NET 4`. However, I'm still getting the `BadImageFormatException`, this time referring to one of my projects.

Additional weirdness: If I deploy to a web server, the application runs.

Possibly relevant -- the bottom of my error message says:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8689;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8670

Is there some way to fix IIS Express to run the right .NET version?

Comment: Why not to target 4.5.x?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416183/unable-to-add-net-3-5-website-to-iis-express

Comment: @DavidTansey as far as I can tell my application default should be running .net 4.0. Is there some way to set it differently for my project? Should I, even?

Comment: When you start the site in debug there should be a dialog box for the ASP.NET Development Server (IIS Express).  The last textbox in that dialog shows the `ASP.NET Version`.  What value is shown for yours?

Comment: Use Jexus Manager to check which application pool is used by this web site, and then change it to a .NET 4 pool. http://jexusmannager.com

Comment: @DavidTansey is that dialog box supposed to show up automatically? is it maybe under options?

Comment: @LexLi I don't see my application in its list of websites.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey Which VS do you use? For VS 2015 you need to add the solution file as a new IIS Express server.

Comment: @LexLi 2015 community. What do you mean "add the solution file as a new IIS Express server"?

Comment: @AdamR.Grey https://jexus.lextudio.com/en/latest/getting-started/features.html Add a custom IIS configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112526/discussion-between-adam-r-grey-and-lex-li).